# Changing node values of DecisionTree after training (using sklearn)

Tags: random-forest, scikit-learn, cart

It is possible to read the node values of a DecisionTree as follows:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
iris = load_iris()

clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

print(clf.tree_.value)
```

Is there a possibility to manipulate those values after the training process and store the changed values back into the data-structure of the tree?

Storing the decision tree:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib

joblib.dump(clf, "clf.pkl")
```

I am currently experimenting a little bit with random forests. I would like to learn the tree structure independently from the leaf node predictions. So the idea is to first learn a random forest with sklearn, afterwards learn the leaf prediction models separately.

**Idea1:** Now, it is possible to store the separately trained leaf node values into another array `learned_leaf_nodes` and just use `node_indices = regr.apply(X)` (which gives you the node indices of each respective sample), instead of `regr.predict(X)` (which gives you the final prediction of each sample), to look up the appropriate node index in `learned_leaf_nodes`. Afterwards, since I use random forests and not single trees, I would have to implement the evaluation of the final prediction.

*Idea1* is an option but I prefer to be able to directly change the leaf node values in my pickled forest.

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish by changing the leaves? Some kind of pruning?

Comment: I would expect that you can just change these at will, have you tried? For a RandomForestClassifier you have each tree in the attribute `_estimators`. Each tree has, `.children_left`, `tree.children_right`, `.feature`, `.threshold` and `.value` - which are arrays